# Garage Door open on it own

Tags: garage-door-opener

When we have a power outage the Garage door will open when the power comes back on!! How do we stop this ? We don't want the door to open when we are gone.

Thank You
Ron

Comment: Please edit your post to add at least some detail about your opener. As it is, we have nothing at all to go on and would be guessing.

Comment: Short of you telling use the make and model of the unit, and what if any non-standard accessories are attached, we really can't tell you anything except go buy a giant UPS so the power will never be interrupted.

Comment: ... but then comparing prices I'd just replace the opener with a new modern unit before I'd buy a giant enough UPS to make sure it never lost power.

Answer (score 1):

If you're away on vacation, then it might be feasible to unplug it while you're gone, but that isn't a good solution because it requires management on your part, and doesn't address what happens when the power goes out while your at the store, or work.

You could try adjusting the limit settings, then simulate a power outage by either unplugging it or flipping the breaker.  It might be that when it normally closes it is very close to a limit and on power up it improperly detects that a safety sensor is detecting a trouble situation.

Other than that you'd have to contact the manufacturer and see if they have a reasonable explanation.

Comment: +1 Great idea to simulate the power loss case so things can be tested and evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a garage door that would open on it's own, at random times. I called the garage door people and they said that the control was shot/worn out so I had them replace the opener.